# Need to check if key is already there and trump value, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var data = [
    ["default_PROJECT", "Allow", "Connect", "Allow", "AddComment", "Allow", "Write",
        "Allow", "ViewComments", "Allow", "ExportData", "Allow", "ExportImage", "Allow",
        "ViewUnderlyingData", "Allow", "Read", "Allow", "ShareView", "Allow", "Filter"
    ],
    ["testing_PROJECT", "Allow", "ExportImage", "Allow", "Write", "Allow", "ViewComments",
        "Allow", "ShareView", "Allow", "Filter", "Allow", "ExportData", "Allow", "Connect", "Allow",
        "Read", "Allow", "ViewUnderlyingData", "Allow", "AddComment", "Allow", "ViewComments", "Deny", "ExportData", "Allow",
        "AddComment", "Deny", "Write", "Allow", "Read", "Deny", "ExportXml", "Deny", "ShareView", "Allow", "Connect", "Allow", "ChangeHierarchy", "Allow",
        "WebAuthoring", "Deny", "ViewUnderlyingData", "Deny", "Filter", "Deny", "ExportImage"
    ]
];


var result = [];
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    var list = data[i];
    result[i] = {
        Project: list[0]
    };
    for (var j = list.length - 1; j >= 1; j = j - 2) {
        var key = list[j];
        var value = list[j - 1];
        result[i][key] = value;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

For some keys there may be more than one value.  If the existing value is allow and there is a value deny for the same key I need the new value of the key to be deny.  For example in the second array the key "ExportImage" should have a value of "Deny" instead of "Allow".  I made objects but how can I check if the values should be overridden?

Comment: Would really recommend another format for your data, but do you want just the latest deny/allow value or does deny take more priority than allow? Allow, Deny, Allow would result in allow or deny?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you store this data in complicated arrays instead of simple objects that actually support key->values?

Comment: I am making the variable result an array of objects from this messy data type.  @juvian Deny takes more priority than allow, if the same key is present and the values are allow and deny it should just by deny.

Comment: you want convert your array in Object with for every element who is not to have "default_PROJECT": "Allow" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of objects is that you can check their value ;) Since "Deny" is superior to all other variables - then let it win, or else the last value.

Case 1: Allow, Deny, Allow, Foo, Bar => **Deny**
Case 2: Allow, Foo, Bar, Allow, Baz => **Baz**

```
for (var j = list.length - 1; j >= 1; j = j - 2) {
    var key = list[j];
    var value = list[j - 1];
    if( result[i][key] !== "Deny" ) {
        result[i][key] = value;
    }
}
```